# Memory Leak in C application debug vs release mode

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I have a very large application 20,000+ lines written in C compiled on a MinGW compiler.  The application has a memory leak when it is compiled in release mode, but does not appear to leak in debug mode.  I have created a running counter to ensure that I have as many free() calls as I have malloc() calloc() calls.

Obviously my codebase is too large to post here, so my question is what kind of differences occur when compiling between debug and release that are capable of causing a memory leak issue that I might want to investigate into?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Wy not just run it under a suitable leak tool, such as valgrind ? That should take you straight to the problem.

Comment: I am trying DrMemory now

Comment: Do you really mean "memory leak" - in other words, you can see that the heap grows as you keep running the program as blocks are not freed when you are in "production" mode? Or do you mean "any memory access errors" - segfaults that go away when you run in debug mode? The latter is easier to explain than the formed... You mentioned that you would try DrMemory. Did you have success?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using different options when compiling for debug rather than compiling for production, the memory structure of your program may be slightly different (in particular, different optimization settings affect this). This shouldn't matter for well-formed code, but if you're reading from or writing to an invalid pointer or beyond the end of an array, what variable you're overwriting may change, turning a harmless error harmful, or vice versa.

Comment: +1 - 99,999% of all debug/release bugs are UB, covered up by different code/memory alignments etc.